# OpenMP parallel region without implicit synchronisation

Tags: performance, openmp

My code has following structure

```
<serial-code-1>
#pragma omp parallel
{
    <parallel-code>
}
<serial-code-2>
```

I want to remove the implicit barrier synchronization at the end of parallel region something like nowait. so that any thread that finishes first can start doing serial-code-2 ( It will require some changes in the serial code 2) but its possible. How is it possible to achieve something like this?

Comment: Could you give a specific reason why you want to do this?  Maybe some code?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps

```
<serial-code-1>
#pragma omp parallel
{
    <parallel-code>
    #pragma omp single
    {
    <serial-code-2>
    }
}
```

The code inside the scope of the `single` directive the serial code will be executed by only one thread, probably the first one to finish executing the parallel code.